# PHP Clean URLs not working as intended

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, clean-urls

I am trying to use a .htaccess file to change my URLs from

```
xxx/table/change.php?id=1
```

to

```
xxx/table/change/1
```

I have the following code in my .htaccess file, which is in the root folder of my web site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^change/([^/\.]+)/?$ change.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^change/([^/\.]+)/?$ change.php?id=$1 [L]
```

However when I restart Apache and visit the desired URL, it still shows up as

```
xxx/table/change.php?id=1
```

Any suggestions?

mod_rewrite is uncommented in the httpd.conf file.

Comment: are you confusing the slashes? supposed to be forward slash `xxx/table/change/1`

Comment: Yes, should be forward slash! My mistake.

Comment: What is `the desired URL` that you're visiting? If you're going to `change.php?id=1` it's not going to redirect you to the clean one.

Comment: Yes, your problem seems to be solved. You can visit the page at `xxx/table/change.php?id=1` and `xxx/table/change/1`. Look at Wikipedia, you can use `/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia` or `/wiki/Wikipedia`. Visiting the long URL does nothing with the .HTAccess. Visiting the shortened one does. Therefore, you can use either.

Comment: @stevether maybe I am confused as to how this works then. I am looking to click an ID on a table, which links to change.php?id=1, however I am looking for it to redirect to change/1

Comment: @Amaerth that would require some 301 redirects.

Comment: Change the href to the clean url

Answer (score 1):

how about you use

```
change/(\d+)$ change.php?id=$1 [L]
```

that is when you visit

```
xxx/table/change/1
```

you are not redirected or 404, you get the correct page. is that what you are looking for?